# How to prove if $A \times C \subseteq B \times D \implies A \subseteq B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

My proof

Given $(x,y) \in A \times C \implies x \in A$ and $y \in C$
since $A \times C \subseteq B \times D$ then $(x,y) \in B \times D$ then $x \in B$ and $y \in D$

since $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ then $A \subseteq B$

Is this a appropriate proof?

Sorry typo in title has been edited.

Comment: 1) How is this `contest-math`? 2) Your question title shows that you're trying to imply $A\subseteq D$ follows from what you're given, but you prove that $A\subseteq B$ follows. Typo?

Comment: I think your proof is fine/appropriate, but you may want to clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $A \subseteq B$, you need to start by choosing any $x \in A$ and conclude by showing that $x \in B$. Notice that the implication is false if $C = \varnothing$; indeed, $\{1\} \times \varnothing = \varnothing \subseteq \{7\} \times \{7\}$ but $\{1\} \not\subseteq \{7\}$.

Otherwise, choose any $x \in A$ and **suppose that there is some $y \in C$**. Then $(x, y) \in A \times C$. But since $A \times C \subseteq B \times D$, we know that $(x, y) \in B \times D$ so that $x \in B$, as desired.

Comment: This proof would just to be proven in general over any sets. But yeah thats what i was trying to show that x is in A and x is in B so that they could be subsets.

Comment: @crash We can't assume that $(x, y) \in A \times C$, because for all we know $C$ could be empty and there wouldn't exist any $y \in C$. Consider the counterexample I used above.

Comment: @Adriano I was mistakenly thinking of most subset implications, where one of the sets being empty results in a vacuous truth. Nice observation. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should check your question again since the inference you have written is false.

Let $A = \mathbb{Q}$, $B = \mathbb{R}$, $C = \mathbb{N}$, and $D = \mathbb{N}$.

Then $A \times C \subseteq B \times D$ however $\mathbb{Q} \not \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Why have I received a down-vote? I have constructed a model where the antecedent is true while the consequent is false. This is a counter-example to the question's claim.